# Prove that the vertices of $n$-gon $P$ that lie inside $n$-gon $Q$ or on its boundary are consecutive.

Tags: geometry, pigeonhole-principle

I found this question on the internet, but I can't find the solution. I believe this question is a pigeon-hole principle type of question. I've tried for specific cases, but I can't prove the statement for all cases of n. Can someone solve prove the statement or at least give a hint of how to do?

" Two regular $n$-gons P and Q ($n\geq 3$) are given in the plane. Prove that the vertices of $P$ that lie inside $Q$ or its boundary are consecutive. (That is, prove that there exist a line separating those vertices of $P$ that lie inside $Q$ or on its boundary from the other vertices of $P$.) "

Comment: You mean, "Two regular n-gons A and B," correct?  This has nothing to do with the pigeonhole principle, I think.  Take a regular pentagon ABCDE.  You can obviously draw a long thin rectangle that encloses only vertices B and E.  According to the problem statement, it's impossible to this with a square.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true.  Consider a square with vertices$$
(\cos \frac{k\pi}{2}, \sin \frac{k\pi}{2}), k=0,1,2,3
$$
and the regular hexagon with vertices at $$
(\cos \frac{k\pi}{3}, \sin \frac{k\pi}{3}), k=0,1,2,3,4,5
$$
The only vertices of one that lie on or inside the other are the vertices they have in common: $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ which are not consecutive vertices of either polygon.